# Конвертер ini2json

Tags: python, json, конвертер

Здравствуйте, есть файл .ini, он имеет вот такое содержание:

```
`[MAIN]
  att=9
  w_obnaruz=1`
```

Как используя файл .json с таким содержанием:

```
`{
  "w_obnaruz": {
  "ini section": "MAIN",
  "json name": ["main", "detect"],
  "val": "bool(old)"
  },
  "att": {
  "ini section": "MAIN",
  "json name": ["main", "att"],
  "val": "old"
  }
 }`
```

на выходе получить .json файл такого плана:

```
`{
  "main": {
      "detect": True,
      "att": 9
   } 
 }`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: import ConfigParser

In [2]: ini_string = """
   ...: [MAIN]
   ...:   att=9
   ...:   w_obnaruz=1
   ...: """

In [3]: config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()

In [4]: import io

In [5]: config.readfp(io.BytesIO('\n'.join([line.strip() for line in ini_string.strip().splitlines()])))

In [6]: import json

In [8]: params = json.loads("""
   ...: {
   ...:   "w_obnaruz": {
   ...:   "ini section": "MAIN",
   ...:   "json name": ["main", "detect"],
   ...:   "val": "bool(old)"
   ...:   },
   ...:   "att": {
   ...:   "ini section": "MAIN",
   ...:   "json name": ["main", "att"],
   ...:   "val": "old"
   ...:   }
   ...:  }
   ...: """)

In [13]: result = {}

In [28]: for item, value in params.items():
    if not value['json name'][0] in result:
        result[value['json name'][0]] = {}
    result[value['json name'][0]][value['json name'][1]] = config.getboolean(value['ini section'], item) if 'bool' in value['val'] else config.get(value['ini section'], item)
   ....:

In [29]: json.dumps(result)
Out[29]: '{"main": {"att": "9", "detect": true}}'
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ, но мне он не совсем понятен. Можете прокомментировать.

Comment: что конкретно не понятно?

Comment: Вот то, что в In [28]

Comment: там, по сути, 4 строчки. какая из них непонятна?

Comment: Последняя строка.

Comment: результату[категория][параметр] присвоить значение этого параметра из конфига в виде булевой если есть подстрока 'bool', иначе присвоить значение этого параметра из конфига как есть

Comment: config.readfp(io.BytesIO('\n'.join([line.strip() for line in ini_string.strip().splitlines()])))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
в чем дело?

Comment: я делал в двойке, мб в тройке ей нужен юникод